# dim(X) must have a positive length when using apply

Tags: r

I have a custom function ShiftType, which returns "Days" if the first value is D, A, P, "Nights" if it is N, and "Swing" if it is S. I am trying to apply this to a column in a dataframe (Roster$Shift.Pattern), with the code 
`Roster$Shift.Type<-apply(Roster$Shift.Pattern, 1, ShiftType)`, what should I change to not get this error and apply the function to each value in Shift.Pattern?

```
ShiftType <-function(x) {
    if (substring(x, 1 ,1) == "D") {return("Days")}
    else if (substring(x, 1 ,1) == "N") {return("Nights")}
    else if (substring(x, 1 ,1) == "S") {return("Swing")}
    else if (substring(x, 1 ,1) == "A") {return("Days")}
    else if (substring(x, 1 ,1) == "P") {return("Days")}
    else {return("None")}
}
```

Comment: To clarify, Roster$Shift.Pattern is stored as a character, I got the same error when it was saved as character or as a factor.

Comment: `substring` is vectorized and there is no need to `apply` it by row. Also, it is highly inefficient to call `substring(x, 1 ,1)` so many times when you can call it only once in your function. Finally you don't need all the `if` `else` statements at all. And your example isn't reproducible. What type of values you have in your data? Are you sure you can't just use `==` or `%in%`?

Comment: In other words, just define `org <- c("D", "A", "P", "N", "S")` and `alt <- c(rep("Days", 3), "Nights", "Swing")` and then, just do `alt[match(substring(Roster$Shift.Pattern, 1 ,1), org)]` and you all set.

Comment: If I just do ShiftType(Roster$Shift.Type), it only gives me the values for the first entry in Roster. The strings are 4-10 characters each, no blanks.

Comment: Did you try my code?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.